# extract the last string after `/` in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to get the last string in a file location. Here is a sample:

```
ids <- c("/Users/st/Desktop/FY2022/G1_Conc fono (MDD)_Form_Number_1.csv",
         "/Users/st/Desktop/FY2022/G1_Conc fono (ADD)_Form_Number_3.csv")

> ids
[1] "/Users/st/Desktop/FY2022/G1_Conc fono (MDD)_Form_Number_1.csv"
[2] "/Users/st/Desktop/FY2022/G1_Conc fono (ADD)_Form_Number_3.csv"
```

I would like to extract the last string after the last `/`.

How can I get the desired output below?

```
> ids
[1] "G1_Conc fono (MDD)_Form_Number_1.csv" "G1_Conc fono (ADD)_Form_Number_3.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `sub` with regular expression:

```
sub('.*\\/', '', ids)
```

output:

```
[1] "G1_Conc fono (MDD)_Form_Number_1.csv" "G1_Conc fono (ADD)_Form_Number_3.csv"
```

---

Or use

```
basename(ids)
```